# SmartSVN - files from multiple branches

Tags: svn, branch, smartsvn

I have one of my project branches open with SmartSVN, but one of the files is showing its branch as "trunk" which the rest show the correct branch name. I'm not sure how this happened but would like to fix it. What happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actaully, this is a feature of Subversion.  Yep, want a particular branch for this folder in your working copy, just switch to it.  It's called a mixed working copy.  The only caveat for this to work, all paths have to be pointed to the same repository.  Now, the fun part is, most people don't use this feature intentionally but somehow manage to stumble upon it through some way or another.

Stumbling on this feature usually involves a switch on a working copy that doesn't get fully switched, often in which is caused by a terminated connection to the Subversion server, resources unavailable on the local machine and the command fails or times out, or the command or application was terminated by the user in the middle of a switch.

No matter the cause, the best solution to resolve this mixed working copy, go to the head of working copy and do another svn switch to the URL you're trying to use.  Just make sure the switch is complete before working on it and before you close SmartSVN.